# How to deploy an msi from visual studio online to azure vm?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-vm-role

I have a build definition on visual studio online which creates an msi installation package using WiX.

How can I automatically deploy the msi package from VSO build agent to Azure VM after the build completes successfully?

Note: I prefer to use a post-build batch or powershell script as part of the build process. The script should copy the msi to the vm and install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Release Management Online. It comes with VSO and allows you to easily orchestrate installing an MSI on any Azure server.

http://nakedalm.com/building-release-pipeline-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

Microsoft just added RM in VSO and its simple to use. I setup an end to end web app deployment, buy as its just a PowerShell to do the install an MSI would be trivial. RM takes care of getting all of the bits to the right spot...

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

Honestly, it sounds hard, but is much easier than trying to do it all yourself.

Comment: I've tried Release Management for a while until the trial ended and because I'm single developer I prefer a small utility or a script. What about TFS Event Handler? Can it listen to visual studio online events?
thanks

Comment: And...I'm back! I now have a new subscription with release management and I'll give it a second try. I'm also thinking about using the new build system on visual studio online which can run power-shell scripts on azure.